# Fully qualified names failing to be recognised correctly with valid grammar

Tags: java, variables, antlr4, fully-qualified-naming

I've got a basic ANTLR-4 grammar at the moment in my Eclipse IDE for Java, and have the following:

```
// Parser

importDeclaration:
    'use' name=FQN ';'
;

// Lexer and terminals

fragment LETTER: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment LETTER_OR_DIGIT: [a-zA-Z0-9_];
ID: LETTER LETTER_OR_DIGIT*;
FQN: ID ('.' ID)*;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
COMMENT: '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN);
LINE_COMMENT: '//' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Hopefully a short and sweet question, when I do the following:

```
use test;
```

I get:

```
line 1:4 mismatched input 'test' expecting FQN
```

And `name` throws a `NullPointerException` if I try to use it.
Except it works fine when I do:

```
use test.test;
```

This has to do with the `('.' ID)*` portion, but have no idea *why* it's happening.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Just realised my code was wrong, had `(FQN|ID)` which was my bad workaround. Fixed it now.

Comment: The input "test" will always be tokenized as an ID token, not a FQN. For an explanation, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541957/antlr4-lexer-rules-dont-work-as-expected

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks Bart. I've seen the answer and it provides a worthy explanation. Is there any possibility you can *help* me, so I can fix it? The other answer does not provide that information.

Comment: Sure, I edited the other question. In your case, the solution would be to change FQN from a lexer rule to a parser rule. This is also how Java and C# parse their imports/using names. HTH

Comment: @BartKiers Beautiful! Thankyou very much Bart. If you didn't close it I would of spammed the accept answer button. :)

Comment: No problem @finnrayment!