# Why does the order of ANTLR4 tokens matter?

Tags: parsing, intellij-idea, token, antlr4

I have a simple grammar that will eventually parse YANG source. When I make when seem to be an arbitrary change the location of the MODULE token the IntelliJ ANTLR4 Plugin can/cannot parse my input.

The input string to be parsed:

```
module x { }
```

Here is the grammar that works without any error:

```
grammar Yang ;

yang: module_open module_close;

module_open : MODULE ID BRACKET_OPEN ;

module_close: BRACKET_CLOSE ;

MODULE: 'module' ;

ID: ([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]*) ;
BRACKET_OPEN: '{' ;
BRACKET_CLOSE: '}' ;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Here is the grammar that fails:

```
grammar Yang ;

yang: module_open module_close;

module_open : MODULE ID BRACKET_OPEN ;

module_close: BRACKET_CLOSE ;

ID: ([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]*) ;

MODULE: 'module' ;

BRACKET_OPEN: '{' ;
BRACKET_CLOSE: '}' ;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

All I'm doing is cutting-pasting the MODULE token definition before/after the ID token, and it always fails if the MODULE definition is after the ID definition.

What am I missing? I see no discussion of order of tokens in the docs!

EDIT: @BartKiers Related Post... [ANTLR4 lexer rules don't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541957/antlr4-lexer-rules-dont-work-as-expected)

Comment: @BartKiers That answer only acknowledges the problem: What are the specific rules of ordering tokens? I fail to see why what amounts to a simple substitution (.aka. MODULE -> "module") should be subject to the order of declaration. Please cite references in the documentation if possible.

Comment: @BartKiers First, thanks for the effort answering newb questions! I get the "The lexer tries to match as much characters as possible" part. But I fail to see why "and when 2 (or more) rules match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first will win." even applies in this situation... I have only one MODULE token definition and only one rule "module_open" that uses that definition."

Comment: @BartKiers The closest I can come to answering my own question is "Token definitions must be declared in the order they are used in the parse tree." or something like that... But what if I use them in a different order in the another parse rule?

Comment: "First, thanks for the effort answering ...": no problem. "... the order they are used in the parse tree." no, that is not how it works. Since my answer is not clear to you, I'll re-open your question and removed the link. Perhaps someone else is able to explain it.

Answer (score 4):

It fails if `module` is after `ID` because the text 'module' is also a valid 'ID'.  If the ID rule appears first, then it has precedence.  That's when the **order** of lexer rules matters, **when two or more lexer rules can match the same input.**  In this case, the one appearing first trumps those that follow; it has precedence.

Your excellent test case here is a perfect and exemplary illustration of this behavior at work.

There used to be in the ANTLR4 documentation here a great article by none other than Sam Harwell that explained this perfectly, but I can no longer find it.

Comment: I don't have the book handy but should be in the lexical discussion.

Answer (score 3):

> From the book of Antlr (section 5.5):
>
> **Matching Identifiers**
>
> In grammar pseudocode, a basic identifier is a nonempty sequence of
>   upper- case and lowercase letters. Using our newfound skills, we know
>   to express the sequence pattern using notation `(...)+`. Because the
>   elements of the sequence can be either uppercase or lowercase letters,
>   we also know that we’ll have a choice operator inside the subrule.
>
> `ID : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+ ; //` match 1-or-more upper or lowercase
>   letters
>
> The only new ANTLR notation here is the range operator: `'a'..'z'`
>   means any character from a to z. That is literally the ASCII code
>   range from 97 to 122. To use Unicode code points, we need to use
>   `'\uXXXX'` literals where `XXXX` is the hexadecimal value for the
>   Unicode character code point value.
>
> As a shorthand for character sets, ANTLR supports the more familiar
>   regular expression set notation.
>
> `ID : [a-zA-Z]+ ; //` match 1-or-more upper or lowercase letters
>
> Rules such as ID sometimes conflict with other lexical rules or
>   literals refer- enced in the grammar such as `'enum'`.

```
grammar KeywordTest;
enumDef : 'enum' '{' ... '}' ;
...
FOR : 'for' ;
...
ID : [a-zA-Z]+ ; // does NOT match 'enum' or 'for'
```

> Rule ID could also
>   match keywords such as `enum` and `for`, which means there’s more than
>   one rule that could match the same string. To make this clearer,
>   consider how ANTLR handles combined lexer/parser grammars such as
>   this. ANTLR collects and separates all of the string literals and
>   lexer rules from the parser rules. Literals such as 'enum' become
>   lexical rules and go immediately after the parser rules but before the
>   explicit lexical rules.
>
> ANTLR lexers resolve ambiguities between lexical rules by favoring the
>   rule specified first. That means your ID rule should be defined after
>   all of your keyword rules, like it is here relative to FOR. ANTLR puts
>   the implicitly gener- ated lexical rules for literals before explicit
>   lexer rules, so those always have priority. In this case, `'enum'` is
>   given priority over ID automatically. Because ANTLR reorders the
>   lexical rules to occur after the parser rules, the following variation
>   on KeywordTest results in the same parser and lexer:

```
grammar KeywordTestReordered;
FOR : 'for' ;
ID : [a-zA-Z]+ ; // does NOT match 'enum' or 'for' ...
enumDef : 'enum' '{' ... '}' ;
...
```