# ANTLR4 - Change token text

Tags: typescript, antlr4

Consider the following lexer rule:

```
TRUE : 'true' | 'TRUE' | '1';
```

I'd like all `TRUE` tokens to be converted to 'true'.

I'm using `antlr4ts`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can only be done by using target specific code. For example, in Java that would look like this:

```
TRUE
 : ( 'true' | 'TRUE' | '1' ) {setText("true");}
 ;
```

Not that the `1` looks suspicious: if you have a rule that matches a number (or integer) and is placed before this `TRUE` rule, then the input `1` will never be tokenised as a `TRUE` token (see: [Why does the order of ANTLR4 tokens matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840873/why-does-the-order-of-antlr4-tokens-matter)).

### EDIT

> How would it look in JavaScript? I'm using `antlr4ts`, and nothing like `setText` seemed to be there.

`setText(...)` is a Lexer method in Java's runtime. If I look at [the antlr4ts code](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts/blob/master/src/Lexer.ts#L91), it looks like you can just set the `public _text` field:

```
/** You can set the text for the current token to override what is in
 *  the input char buffer.  Set `text` or can set this instance var.
 */
public _text: string | undefined;
```

In other words, try this:

```
TRUE
 : ( 'true' | 'TRUE' | '1' ) {this._text = "true";}
 ;
```

Comment: How would it look in JavaScript? I'm using `antlr4ts`, and nothing like `setText` seemed to be there.

Comment: Try my **EDIT** @JohnSmith