# ANTLR4 zero or more repetitions in lexer

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm declaring something like this:

`ID : [a-zA-Z0-9_]+('.'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)* ;`

The idea is that this must match just `fkdnb` or `bfdgkdjf.cbkdsv.encsdj.nbnkj` etc.
But the expression above doesn't match the string without dots, e.g. `fkdnb`, although I thought `*` was supposed to mean "zero or more times".

How can this expression be fixed to match the patterns described above?

Comment: `*` does mean zero or more and this regex should match `fkdnb` just fine. Please post a [MCVE] that shows that `fkdnb` isn't being matched.

Comment: You'll probably have another lexer rule placed above `ID` that also matches the input `fkdnb`. And because it is placed above it (and matches the same). See: this Q&A which will probably be your issue as ell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840873/why-does-the-order-of-antlr4-tokens-matter

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks for the help, indeed that was it

Comment: Good to hear that @Overpass. In that case I'll close this question and link it to the answered Q&A.