# Array support for Hplsql.g4 or Hive.g4

Tags: hive, antlr4

Good day everyone,
I am using antlr4 to create a parser and lexer for Hive SQL (Hplsql.g4).
I believe this is the latest grammar file.
https://github.com/AngersZhuuuu/Spark-Hive/blob/master/hplsql/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/hive/hplsql/Hplsql.g4

However, I found at least two additions that are needed: IF and array indices.
For example, in a select statement, I may have:
a) SELECT if(a>8,12,20) FROM x
b) SELECT column_name[2] FROM x

Both are valid in Hive but both do not parse when I create a parser and lexer for java from the Hplsql.g4 above.  I added an expression for the IF and it appears to work.

I added

```
 expr :
     ...
     | expr_if  //I added
```

and a new rule:

```
expr_if : 
       T_IF T_OPEN_P bool_expr T_COMMA expr T_COMMA expr T_CLOSE_P  //I added
     ;
```

However, figuring out how to allow an array index is not so easy because the grammar allows aliases:

```
select a from x
select a alias_of_a from x
select a[1] from x
select a[1] alias_of_a from x
```

should all be valid.
I tried adding a new expression for this like so:

```
expr :
     ...
     | expr_array //I added

expr_array : 
       T_OPEN_SB L_INT T_OPEN_CB  //I added
     ;
```

This didn't work for me.  (T_OPEN_SB L_INT T_OPEN_CB are [ integer ] respectively). I tried so many variations on this as well. My questions are:

1. Am I using the right grammar file - if not is there a newer one with IF and array handling?
2. Has anyone been successful in extending this grammar to handle my cases above?

---

As per Bart's recommendations:
I updated *ident*.
I updated *expr_atom*.
I added *array_index*.
I had // | '[' .*? ']' commented out before.

Test Sql: select a[0] from t
Result:
line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'selecta[0]'
line 1:8 mismatched input '[0]'

Tree
(program (block stmt (stmt select) (stmt (expr_stmt (expr (expr_atom (ident a)))))) [0] from t)

I feel like the problem is somehow related to select_list_alias below.
With select_list_alias containing ident and T_AS optional, ident is matching the array index.
I can't reconcile why this happens, especially since ident has been updated.

Excerpt from Hplsql.sql:

```
select_list :           
       select_list_set? select_list_limit? select_list_item (T_COMMA select_list_item)*
     ;
select_list_item :
       (ident T_EQUAL)? expr select_list_alias? 
     | select_list_asterisk   
     ;
select_list_alias :
       {!_input.LT(1).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("INTO") && !_input.LT(1).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("FROM")}? T_AS? ident
     | T_OPEN_P T_TITLE L_S_STRING T_CLOSE_P
     ;
```

If I pass in a simple SQL stmt to grun such as

```
select a[1] from t
```

The parse tree should look similar to this:

[image: Parse tree for select a from t]

Instead of expr_atom, I want to see expr_array where it would split into expr_atom for the a and array_index for the [1].

Note that there is one SQL statement here.  With my existing g4, the array index [1] (and the remainder of the stmt) gets parsed as a separate SQL statement.

Bart, I see from your parse tree that parsing resulted in two SQL statements from "select a[0] from t" - I was getting the same situation.

I will continue to explore different approaches - I am still suspicious of the select_list_alias which has `T_AS? ident` at the end.  Just to confirm, I have commented out one line from ident_part like this: // | '[' .*? ']'

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for the comment.  Yes, I saw that in the grammar.  It seems like 

select_list_alias :
       {!_input.LT(1).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("INTO") && !_input.LT(1).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("FROM")}? T_AS? ident

is causing a match with ident
However, I thought the parsers match the longest rule (longest set of tokens) first.

Comment: Bart, thanks for this - I will take a read.  I am considering removing the individual tokens '[' and ']' so I can dedicate them to array index case (as a parser rule). I am worried that this is a bad approach.  If I take what you are saying, there is no way to add array index handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: `[ ... ]` will be tokenised as a `L_ID` token. If you don;t want that, remove the `| '[' .*? ']'` part:

```
fragment
L_ID_PART  :
             [a-zA-Z] ([a-zA-Z] | L_DIGIT | '_')*                           // Identifier part
            | ('_' | '@' | ':' | '#' | '$') ([a-zA-Z] | L_DIGIT | '_' | '@' | ':' | '#' | '$')+     // (at least one char must follow special char)
            | '"' .*? '"'                                                   // Quoted identifiers
            // | '[' .*? ']' <-- removed
            | '`' .*? '`'
            ;
```

and create/edit the grammar like this:

```
expr_atom :
       date_literal
     | timestamp_literal
     | bool_literal
     | expr_array // <-- added
     | ident
     | string
     | dec_number
     | int_number
     | null_const
     ;

// new rule
expr_array
     : ident array_index+
     ;

// new rule
array_index
     : T_OPEN_SB expr T_CLOSE_SB
     ;
```

The rules above will cause `select a[1] alias_of_a from x` to be parsed successfully, but wil fail on input like `select a[1] alias_of_a from [identifier]`: the `[identifier]` will not be matched as an identifier.

You could try adding something like this:

```
ident :
       L_ID
     | T_OPEN_SB ~T_CLOSE_SB+ T_CLOSE_SB // <-- added
     | non_reserved_words
     ;
```

which will parse `select a[1] alias_of_a from [identifier]` properly, but have no good picture of the whole grammar (or deep knowledge of HPL/SQL) to determine if that will mess up other things :)

### EDIT

With my proposed changes, the grammar looks like this: https://gist.github.com/bkiers/4aedd6074726cbcd5d87ede00000cd0d (I cannot post it here on SO because of the char limit)

Parsing `select a[0] from t` with this will result in the parse tree:

[image]

And parsing `select a[0] from [t]` with this will result in this parse tree:

[image]

You're also able to test it by running the following Java code:

```java
String source = "select a[0] from [t]";
HplsqlLexer lexer = new HplsqlLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
HplsqlParser parser = new HplsqlParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
ParseTree root = parser.program();

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Antlr AST");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(parser.getRuleNames()), root);
viewer.setScale(1.5);
panel.add(viewer);
frame.add(panel);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Very nice answer.  In fact, I didn't say that I have commented out:
  // | '[' .*? ']' <-- removed
as you showed.  Baby steps.

Somewhere along the line I believe I added 
expr_atom :
...     
      | ident array_index* // <-- added `array_index*`

but, by itself, didn't seem to do the trick (or I had other changes interfering).
 
I like your suggestion of expanding the definition of ident.  I will go this route and see what happens elsewhere.  I have a few things to explore.  Thanks for the valuable response.

Comment: Bart, I added results of my testing to the end of the original post - I didn't have enough space in the Comments.

Comment: Checkout my **EDIT** @MikeLapenna. Not sure if my point came across: `'[' .*? ']' ` needs to be removed, otherwise it won't work because of how  the lexer works (explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541957/antlr4-lexer-rules-dont-work-as-expected )

Comment: Checkout my EDIT @Bart (and thanks again for your research into this).  Note that parsing result in one SQL smt.

Comment: Ah, 2 stmt's, yeah I just now see that. Hmmm, I don't think I have a quick solution here. If I can spend more time on it, I might take a look into the grammar, else I will remove this answer.

Comment: @MikeLapenna the grammar contains predicates which are not evaluated in the IntelliJ preview plugin. I slightly adjusted the grammar (and updated the Gist) and added some Java code  that you can run to see the real parse trees being generated (that do not contain 2 `stmt`'s)

Comment: Bart, I am grateful that you are taking this on.  I am sure many others will benefit from our conversation.  I will take a look at your revision and get back to you.

Comment: Success!  These cases parse correctly as I hoped:

select a from [t]
select a[9] alias_name from t
select a[9] alias_name from [t]
select a alias_name from [t]

Bart, I am grateful for your help.  I am now going to proceed with parsing numerous SQL stmts for regression testing.  Outstanding work.

Comment: Good to hear it @MikeLapenna